# Retriving specific element from Hibernate's bag with Native Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is part of my **mapping**:

```
<class name="org.me.MainObject" table="objects">
   <bag name="associatedIds" table="object_associations" lazy="false">
      <element column="association_id" not-null="true" type="long" />
   </bag>
</class>
```

This is my **query**:

```
SELECT {o.*}, {oa.*}
FROM objects (NOLOCK) o INNER JOIN object_associations (NOLOCK) oa ON o.id = oa.object_id
WHERE o.id = ?
```

This is my **java code**:

```
final Query query getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(ABOVE_QUERY)
     .addEntity("o", MainObject.class)
     .addJoin("oa", "o.associatedIds")
     .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

query.setParameter("objectId", someIdVariable);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<MainObject> resultList = query.list();
```

**Problem** is that since *associatedIds* is simply a List of Long objects (not entities) in the *MainObject* class, this code fails with a null pointer exception in SQLQueryParser class (resolveProperties method).

I wonder if there is a way to do this. If I remove the Alias and Join from the query, or if I replace {oa.*} with oa.*, hibernate will issue another SELECT statement to load the association ids. But that's exactly what I don't want it to do. I don't want Hibernate to issue another select and more importantly I want to write the query myself so I can provide the *NOLOCK* hint.

Comment: Also, if I try {oa.association_id}, I get the following error (which makes sense since associatedIds isn't an entity):

org.hibernate.QueryException: No column name found for property [association_id] for alias [oa]